# WinError 10060 A connection attempt failed

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='ponnamanjaneyulu1@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#########'
EMAIL_POST = '587'
```

above are the settings for the Django core mail module.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
emailFrom = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        emailTo ='ponnamnarasimha1@gmail.com'
        text_content = 'Your content here'
        email_subject = "Subject here"
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(email_subject, text_content, emailFrom, [emailTo], )
        msg.send()
        return HttpResponse('We have sent a email verification please check your email')
```

I am using its EmailMultiAlternatives to send emails to users. When I try to build the program with the Gmail SMTP it throws the following error

> 'Errno 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'.

I am doing this in my sample project, somewhere else, or let me know where I am going wrong. ?
please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
EMAIL_POST = '587'
```

to

```
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
```